# How to set snapshot directory name in Solr?

Tags: solr

In Solr (7.4) through Collections API I'm requesting a backup

```
http://localhost:5008/solr/my_collection/replication?command=backup&location=/backups&numberToKeep=1
```

What I get after backup's done is `/backups/snapshot.YYYYmmDDhhMMssSSS` **but** `hh` is 2 before start of the backup.
Date field in index are also 2 hours before system time but log times are not, they're consistent with system time.

As I'm OK with date in index, I rather prefer to have time in `/backups/snapshot.YYYYmmDDhhMMssSSS` consistent with system time. Is there a way to set it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First - the reason for the two hour difference is that Solr uses UTC for all it timestamps without any timezone information. The log entries are in your local timezone. Usually the timestamps on your system is also stored in UTC, while being displayed in your local timezone when you list them.

You can give the parameter `name` to tell [Solr to use any name that you want yourself](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/making-and-restoring-backups.html). That means you'll have to resolve the actual values yourself before calling the backup command, but it allows you to use any format as preferred.

> The snapshot will be created in a directory called snapshot.. If a name is not specified then the directory name would have the following format: snapshot.<yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS>

If you run your script through bash you can get a timestamp based on seconds by using:

```
$ date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S
20181022095739
```

You also have %N to give you the current number of nanoseconds, so if you really need the millisecond precision, you can extract the first three digits from that value.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure `/etc/default/solr.in.sh` and add `SOLR_TIMEZONE="Europe/Paris"` for example

Comment: Thanks. It works as expected. Time in dir name is in desired timezone but does it impact on date field in index?